# Saucelabs: Can we use Dynamic Device Allocation using Virtual devices?

Tags: python, appium, appium-android, saucelabs

We're currently encountering the error below and we figured out it's because the device that we are trying to use is currently not available.

```
HOOK-ERROR in before_scenario: MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: ***ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/wd/hub/session/784aec08b0024b828d2d3e091eb5fdc2?ref=9601c9d4cb694b238fcec5ede61b960f (Caused by ResponseError('too many redirects'))
```

We're trying to do a Dynamic device allocation but for Virtual devices in Saucelabs. But we're getting the error below:

```
HOOK-ERROR in before_scenario: SessionNotCreatedException: Message: There is no device that matches your criteria. DesiredCapabilities: ***"capabilities":***"firstMatch":[***"appium:appActivity":"com.quipper.school.assignment.ui.SplashActivity","platformName":"Android","appium:deviceName":".*Google.*","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:platformVersion":"11","appium:app":"storage:filename\u003dapp-global-rc-July-5.apk","appium:appPackage":"com.quipper.school.assignment.rc","sauce:options":***"name":"Android login and signup + @login,@sign_up07-12 01:01","sessionCreationRetry":"2","sessionCreationTimeout":"3000"***]***
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'Sauce Labs RDC', ip: 'N/A', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.176+', java.version: '11.0.19'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

We're using `devicename : ['Google Pixel 3 GoogleAPI Emulator']` as our device and we wanted to have a family of available Google Pixel devices with Android 11 to use. I can't seem to figure out how to assign it dynamically. Tried `['.*Google.*']` , `['.*Google Pixel.*']`, `['.*Google.*Pixel.*GoogleAPI.*Emulator.*']` but still nothing works.

Here is our current `environment.py`:

```
import os
import time
from appium import webdriver
from selenium.common import InvalidSessionIdException
from app.application import Application


def before_scenario(context, scenario):

    sauce_username = os.environ["SAUCE_USERNAME"]
    sauce_access_key = os.environ["SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY"]

    desired_caps = {
        'platformName': os.environ["platformname"],  # os
        'platformVersion': os.environ["platformversion"],  # version
        'deviceName': os.environ["devicename"],  # device name
        'automationName': os.environ["automationname"],
        'appPackage': os.environ["apppackage"],
        'appActivity': os.environ["appactivity"],
        'app': os.environ["app"],
        'sauce:options': {  # Sauce custom capabilities
            "sessionCreationRetry": "2",
            "sessionCreationTimeout": "3000",
            "name": os.environ["jobname"] + time.strftime("%m-%d %H:%M")
        }
    }

    # launch app
    context.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://{}:{}@ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/wd/hub".format(sauce_username, sauce_access_key), desired_caps)
    time.sleep(30)
    if context.driver.session_id is None:
        context.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://{}:{}@ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/wd/hub".format(sauce_username, sauce_access_key), desired_caps)
    else:
        context.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        context.app = Application(context.driver)


def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    if hasattr(context, 'driver') and context.driver is not None:
        context.driver.save_screenshot("screenshot" + time.strftime("%y-%m-%d %H%M") + ".png")
        status = str(scenario.status)
        context.driver.execute_script('sauce:job-result=' + status)
        context.driver.quit()
        try:
            if context.driver.session_id:
                context.driver.quit()
        except InvalidSessionIdException:
            return
    else:
        return True
```